# Change order of reported Mac address

Tags: windows, networking

We have an old legacy application that uses Mac address for validating a license.

Sometimes this license trips up when attempting to start the app without a network cable connected.

Is it possible with a registry tweak to change (or some other way) the order of what windows reports is the first Mac address? Ie. The order of what windows prints when you run the getmac command from a console window.

Answer (score 0):

If its tripping up when there is no cable plugged in, maybe installing the MS loopback adapter is an option and get your legacy program to look at this mac id, as this should be on and working all the time.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2777200/installing-the-microsoft-loopback-adapter-in-windows-8-and-windows-ser

run C:\Windows\System32\hdwwiz.exe, and step through the wizard.